# Finding IAM Roles Last Used Date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there any way to find Last Used Date of an IAM Role? This is required for Auditing purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the last time a service permission granted to a role was used.  The most recently used service permission will effectively be a "last used date" for the IAM role as a whole.

The easiest way to see this data is to click on the role in the IAM section of the Management Console, and click on the "Access Advisor" tab.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor.html

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.